# Datagridview databinding when create new object on create new row

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I've got a little problem with data-binding between `DataGridView` and a `PropertyGrid`.

Here is the code from the object I am binding to and the `DataGridView`:

```
 public class Effort
 {
     public BindingList<EffortCalculationRelation> CalculationRelations { get; set; }
     public int ID { get; set; }
     // more properties

     public Effort()
     {
         CalculationRelations = new BindingList<EffortCalculationRelation>();
         CalculationRelations.Clear();

         for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
         {
             CalculationRelations.Add( new EffortCalculationRelation() { ID = i, Name = "Round:" + i.ToString(), calculation = "Some calc" });
         }
     }

     public Effort(int id) : this()
     {
         this.ID = id;
         // Load all other properties
     }

     public class EffortCalculationRelation
     {
         public int ID { get; set; }
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public string calculation { get; set; }


         public int Save()
         {
             // save or insert and return id or 0 on fail
             if (this.ID > 0)
             {
                 return this.Update();
             }
             else
             {
                 return this.Insert();
             }
         }
         public string Delete()
         {
             // delete and return "" or errormsg on fail
             return "";
         }
         private int Insert()
         {
             // insert and return id or 0 on fail
             return ID;
         }
         private int Update()
         {
             // return affected rows or 0 on fail
             return 1;
         }

         public string Representation
         {
             get { return String.Format("{0}: {1}", ID, Name); }
         }
     }
 }
```

The datagridview connection is realy simple an only just a little style:

```
  public test()
  {
     effort = new Effort(1209);
     dgv.DataSource = effort.CalculationRelations;
     dgv.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
     dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
     //this.dgv.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
     dgv.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
     dgv.ReadOnly = true;
     dgv.SelectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
     {
         var selectedObjects =
              (from System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow r in dgv.SelectedRows
              where r.DataBoundItem != null && r.DataBoundItem.GetType() == typeof(EffortCalculationRelation)
              select r.DataBoundItem).ToArray();

         // pg is a propertygrid
         this.pg.SelectedObjects = selectedObjects;
     };
  }
```

So and my problem is, when I select the new row in the datagridview, that no properties are displayed in the propertygrid.

When I select a row that has an object in the list at the moment I load it, then I can edit the properties.

So could you please help?

Comment: The code you have given doesn't work as is. I'm going to edit it with the code I believe you skipped but please check that what I have done is correct and with further code give exactly what you have.

Comment: sorry i've see, and it's corrct, it's a cut version from my working source.

Comment: Must you have the multiple selection available? This works very nicely if you use `SelectedObject` and not `SelectedObjects`. I'm looking at why the new row doesn't work now.

Comment: Yes multiple selections are available, and I need all selected objects, because it must be possible to change values for all selected objects a the same time. It works fine but not when i select the new row.

Comment: The why of this happening is very straight forward actually - no databound item exists for the new row until it has been committed. Still trying to find a solution though, currently experimenting with BindingSource to see if that helps.

Comment: But when it not exists, how is it possible that that the default values are shown, because when i click on the new row the 'Representation' Propery has values insertet (only if set in constructor) so it must create a object

Comment: Have a look inside the debugger, there is no DataBoundItem yet, it is null. Only once the row is committed do you have the item created.

Comment: hm, when i look inside the debugger, the databindlist has the new item in the list (create with `AddNewCore`) but the datagridview has in the row databounditem = null, thats a realy big mistake i think so. Did you know any workaround?

Comment: I've found a slight work around - am writing it up as an answer now, it isn't ideal but it is the best I found.

Comment: Well there you go - sadly not as good a workaround as I though would be possible - the fact that the grid keeps new rows in this virtual state is really inconvenient. Maybe you will find something better, or another user here might have a better solution. If you do find a good approach, do come post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the new row does not show in the property grid is that its `DataBoundItem` is null so is removed by your LINQ statement `where r.DataBoundItem != null`. <sup>1</sup>

I agree with you that this is very annoying behaviour, particularly since the object has in some sense been created.

I had thought there was a viable workaround of in certain circumstance binding the property grid to the new object in either the parent `Effort` object or in a `BindingSource` using some code like:

```
var selectedObjects =
        (from System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.SelectedRows
        where r.DataBoundItem != null && r.DataBoundItem.GetType() == typeof(Effort.EffortCalculationRelation)
        select r.DataBoundItem).ToArray();

if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.IsNewRow && dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
{
    // I tried accessing the parent object like this:
    //Effort.EffortCalculationRelation ecr = effort.CalculationRelations[effort.CalculationRelations.Count - 1];
    //propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = ecr;

    // Or accessing a binding source like:
    propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = calculationRelations.Current;
}
else
{
    propertyGrid1.SelectedObjects = selectedObjects;
}
```

I experimented with these variations a bit, as well as adding these items into the SelectedObjects array, thinking something would meet your requirements but what I eventually realised was **shifting focus from the new row to the property grid before the DataGridView had committed the new row meant that the new row was lost and could no longer be edited**.

So - what to do?

If I was in your spot I'd consider one of two things:

- Allow direct editing in the grid of some form - maybe just to the new row.

  Something like this in the selection changed event would work:

  ```
  if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.IsNewRow)
  {
      dataGridView1.CurrentRow.ReadOnly = false;
  }
  else
  {
      dataGridView1.CurrentRow.ReadOnly = true;
  }
  ```
- Keep the grid as is but don't allow new rows - instead handle new objects between a seperate row creation panel.

---

<sup>1</sup> This works this way apparently by design - the DataBoundItem is not committed uptil you leave the grid. There is a little discussion including the `DataGridView` code in question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/7cf387d0-96e8-437e-86c3-14a411be0001).

Comment: Greate thanks David, I use an other workaround. I create a button, that adds a new item to the databoundlist, when it's createt the grid will display the object.